# How can I convert a list to a string in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, interpolation

> `join` works BUT i want to keep the double quotes join gives me this
>
> `[ben,linda,john]`
>
> BUT i want this
>
> `["ben", "linda", "john"]`

this is getting crazy, spent over 2 hours trying to fix this
i want to pass in a list as a string variable
why can't terraform just take in my list as a string? why is this so difficult?

so i have

`name = ["ben", "linda", "john"]`

and i want to pass this to variable used in terrform

`var.name`

why can't terrform take this as is?

i get the error saying epxtected a string and i can not find a solution online after sarching everywhere

i have been able to get

`[ ben,linda,john ]` using `join(",", var.name)` but i want `["ben", "linda", "john"]`

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.18
+ provider.aws v2.42.0
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Comment: Can you share your full Terraform code as a [mcve] and then share the command you are running at the command line as well please?

Comment: terraform version `v0.12.18` also updated question

Comment: nopes not working..i tried many things already..spent over 2 hours on this thing

Comment: no this is custom variable and i need to pass what i set as variable as is..this is similar to passing subnet_ids...how will you pass subnet_ids? should be same

Comment: If you can't share your Terraform code then no one will be able to show what you're doing wrong here.

Comment: i think i have added enough information..i mentioned what i have tried and what is generated and what expected outcome is..also stated version of terraform..i mean what is missing?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Conversion from list to string always requires an explicit decision about how the result will be formatted: which character (if any) will delimit the individual items, which delimiters (if any) will mark each item, which markers will be included at the start and end (if any) to explicitly mark the result as a list.

The syntax example you showed looks like JSON. If that is your goal then the easiest answer is to use [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) to convert the list directly to JSON syntax:

```
jsonencode(var.names)
```

This function produces compact JSON, so the result would be the following:

```
["ben","linda","john"]
```

---

Terraform provides a ready-to-use function for JSON because its a common need. If you need more control over the above decisions then you'd need to use more complex techniques to describe to Terraform what you need. For example, to produce a string where each input string is in quotes, the items are separated by commas, and the entire result is delimited by `[` and `]` markers, there are three steps:

- Transform the list to add the quotes: `[for s in var.names : format("%q", s)]`
- Join that result using `,` as the delimiter: `join(", ", [for s in var.names : format("%q", s)])`
- Add the leading and trailing markers: `"[ ${join(",", [for s in var.names : format("%q", s)])} ]"`

The above makes the same decisions as the JSON encoding of a list, so there's no real reason to do exactly what I've shown above, but I'm showing the individual steps here as an example so that those who want to produce a different list serialization have a starting point to work from.

For example, if the spaces after the commas were important then you could adjust the first argument to `join` in the above to include a space:

```
"[ ${join(", ", [for s in var.names : format("%q", s)])} ]"
```

Comment: this is crazy that this is all that it takes..why cant i just dump the var as a string? i mean why cant that be possible? i don't see any reason not to. This is custom variable and i have specified that terraform should just take what is in there as a string and use the value as-is

Comment: so where in my terraform file do i put this line? `jsonencode(var.names)`?

Comment: also this is an array not json.. `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: perfect works! used this `"[${join(", ", [for s in var.names : format("%q", s)])}]"`..thanks!

Comment: Replace your existing use of `join(",", var.name)` with `jsonencode(var.name)`, if JSON syntax is what you want.

Comment: I would've gladly shown you where to put that in your existing Terraform configuration if you had shared your existing Terraform configuration as @ydaetskcor kindly advised, but hopefully that's sufficient.

Comment: Work for me.

------------
resource "t1" "t2" {
.....
description  = "[ ${join(", ", [for k, v in local.common_tags :"${k} => ${v}"])} ]"
}

Comment: Thanks. the `format("%q"...` part did the trick :) Exactly what I needed.

Comment: why not simple `join(",", var.my_list)` ?

Comment: The original question above says that the requester tried `join(",", var.name)` and that didn't produce the format they wanted. If you want the format that `join` alone would produce then indeed you can just use `join`, but that would be a different question than this one.